# Getting imagename and make link from <img> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox

With jQuery, I want to make **all images** under a **specific path** on a site clickable and showing a big image using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net), which is a lighbox variant plugin for jQuery.

My small images are located under *"images/products/small"*, the big ones under *"images/products/big"* and the imagename is always the same

The page is showing the image with the following code:

```
<img src="images/products/small/hat.jpg" alt="Nice hat">
```

What i want is some jQuery script that makes this into:

```
<a href="images/products/big/hat.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="images/products/small/hat.jpg" alt="Nice hat"></a>
```

Maybe the part with setting class on the link tag can be skipped and just activate fancybox on the element directly with *$(elm).fancybox();*

I was looking around a bit and it looks like the jQuery functions *"attr"* and *"wrap"* might be useful, but with my currently limited jQuery skills I can't really connect the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find all of the images, and then as you suspected, you can use `wrap` if you really want the structure to be modified:

```
$('some_parent_selector img[src*=/small]').wrap(function() {
    return "<a href='" + this.src.replace("/small", "/large") + "' class='fancybox'/>";
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/obacu4) (once you click the button, the elements will be wrapped; this may not be immediately obvious visually, but if you use Firebug or Dev Tools or even just click them...).

You were on the right track with `attr`, btw, but it happens that the `src` attribute is one of those that's reflected as a property on the HTMLImageElement DOM object, so you don't need to use `attr`.

Comment: Always better to use attr() to normalize it, imo.  You never know when some crazy browser is going to decide to change the DOM in weird ways.  Maybe I'm just paranoid...it's not like that's ever happened before xD

Comment: @Mike: `id` and `src` are safe, as is `href` on anchor tags (and `value` on `input`). Even if you're being paranoid, you can rely on those. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that you could reference your element with *this* within the jQuery function. It was the dot that was missing in my brains! :)